# Dropdown menu. make it show onclick and not onmouseover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, touchscreen

I'm using this Dynamic Drive dropdown menu ( http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/ ---- js source at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/chromejs/chrome.js ) on my page.

The author says: All event handlers added to the menu are now unobstrusive, allowing you to define your own "onmouseover" or "onclick" events on the menu items *(but he doesn't explain how to newbies like me)*.

Here's a bit part of the code:

```
<div class="chromestyle" id="chromemenu">
    <ul>
        <li><h2><a href="#" rel="dropmenu1">Me&amp;myself</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#" rel="dropmenu2">Napoli</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#" rel="dropmenu3">Technology</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="/ufo.php">UFO</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#" rel="dropmenu4">Anime</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="/maps/map.php">Cartine geografiche</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="/calcio.php">Il calcio</a></h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--1st drop down menu -->                                                   
    <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv">
    <a href="/">.: Home</a>
    <a href="/interess.php">.: About me</a>
    <a href="/blog/">.: My Blog</a>
    <a href="/gallery/">.: My Photo Gallery</a>
    <a href="/guestbook/guestbook.php">.: My Guestbook</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that touchscreen devices can't show drop down menus because you don't have a mouse and you can only tap on the screen, hence why I want to make the drop down menus clickable, now that I have written a proper mobile css stylesheet.

I googled without luck, and tried substituting onclick="" to rel="" but unfortunately it didn't work.

Any hints?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js for this drop down menu seems to have been last updated in 2008 so be a little cautious as to its compatibility with modern browsers and technologies.

I would suggest googling for a more recent drop down js solution.

OR

you could take a look at this list of drop down solutions ( http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/ ) the list was updated only last month, have a good look through and you might find a better solution than the Dynamic Drive drop down.

Comment: You're right, I've switched to http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu which has been updated some weeks ago and works well on smartphones too.